# How do I properly install NuSMV since, upon downloading, the bin file does not contain .exe file?

Tags: download, installation, tar, model-checking, nusmv

I am following a tutorial to install NuSMV on Windows 10. It downloads fine but upon extracting the files from the zipped (.tar) folder, I do not find the the .exe file in the "bin" folder which is supposed to be there (of course). I am downloading it from NuSMV website. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `NuSMV` on Windows, one should

- [follow this link](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/download/getting_bin-v2.html),
- fill the following form

  [image]
- click either on `Register` or `Do not register`, according to their preference
- select the correct download link from [the page that is automatically opened after the last step](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/bin/bin_download2-v2.cgi)

  *(For **Windows** that would be [**Windows Archive 64-bit (x86)**](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/distrib/NuSMV-2.6.0-win64.tar.gz).)*

  [image]
- unpack the downloaded file, which shows **NuSMV.exe** inside the `bin` subdirectory:

  [image]
- navigate to such directory in a terminal, and run the following command:

  ```
  ~$ ./NuSMV.exe -int
  *** This is NuSMV 2.6.0 (compiled on Wed Oct 14 15:37:51 2015)
  *** Enabled addons are: compass
  *** For more information on NuSMV see <http://nusmv.fbk.eu>
  *** or email to <nusmv-users@list.fbk.eu>.
  *** Please report bugs to <Please report bugs to <nusmv-users@fbk.eu>>

  *** Copyright (c) 2010-2014, Fondazione Bruno Kessler

  *** This version of NuSMV is linked to the CUDD library version 2.4.1
  *** Copyright (c) 1995-2004, Regents of the University of Colorado

  *** This version of NuSMV is linked to the MiniSat SAT solver. 
  *** See http://minisat.se/MiniSat.html
  *** Copyright (c) 2003-2006, Niklas Een, Niklas Sorensson
  *** Copyright (c) 2007-2010, Niklas Sorensson

  NuSMV >
  ```

---

**Q: I followed the instructions but the executable is not there, what should I do?** *You may want to check whether your antivirus program put the executable in quarantine.*

Answer (score 0):

You may use 'command prompt' to start NuSMV interface. I have used it using the 'command prompt in Windows 10.